# REGEX .net\powershell match string between strings

Tags: regex, powershell

This might be very simple. I just want to match all strings within strings, including new line breaks.
Example:

**textfile:**

```
MESSAGE BEGIN

mary had a little lamb.

little lamb

MESSAGE END
```

**output expectation:**

```
mary had a little lamb.

little lamb
```

Here is what i currently have. it works okay, except everything is in 1 line.

**Code (I currently have):**

```
$pattern= Regex::"MESSAGE BEGIN(.*?)MESSAGE END"

[regex]::Match($text,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
```

**result:**

```
mary had a little lamb.little lamb
```

I would like it to respect line breaks, so that they are not all crammed together.

Comment: Are you sure that the line breaks are not there?  I suggest that maybe they are there, but you just can't see them in the tool you are using.

Comment: @wp78de But it appears that dot is already matching across newlines.

Comment: Content comes from a text file, where there is a return, I guess. It matches exactly what I want it to match, but it doesn't respect the newline\break. I am sorry if I am using the wrong term.

Comment: If the line breaks are in your file, then the should be retained. I guess the problem is the way you read the file.

Comment: ([\s\S]*?) not quite. but it worked better than others. same output as my original (.*?)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/EWSI4j/1/

Comment: You guys are all phenomenal trying this next, (Get-Content $singlefile.FullName) -join "`n"

Comment: wp78de's suspicon was correct. I got it workinbg using ([\s\S]*?) and by using the right commands in ps. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Use look arounds:

[`(?<=MESSAGE BEGIN)[\s\S]+(?=MESSAGE END)`](https://regex101.com/r/rzBfeA/4)

Will match any text between (but not including) `MESSAGE BEGIN` and `MESSAGE END`.

For discussion of supported regular expresions in Powershell visit: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/10/21/powershell-regex-crash-course-part-4-of-5/

Answer (score 1):

The first part here is to use a pattern like `[\s\S]*` instead of the `.` to match newlines too. You want to match lazy`+?`/`*?` to avoid to match too much (e.g. from the first MESSAGE BEGIN to the last MESSAGE END if there are multiple message blocks.)

[Pattern](https://regex101.com/r/EWSI4j/1/):

```
MESSAGE BEGIN([\s\S]*?)MESSAGE END
```

or if you just want the inner part use look-arounds (still lazy `*?`):

```
(?<=MESSAGE BEGIN)[\s\S]*?(?=MESSAGE END)
```

End-to-end code sample:

```
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\a.txt")

$matches = [regex]::matches($text, "MESSAGE BEGIN([\s\S]*?)MESSAGE END");
ForEach($match in $matches) {
  #Write-Output $match.Value.Trim(); #if you use look-arounds
  Write-Output $match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, MESSAGE BEGIN([\s\S]*?)MESSAGE END did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MESSAGE BEGIN(\s|\S)*MESSAGE END
```

(.*?) matches all characters, **except for line terminators**.

**\s** matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

**\S** matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])

Include a bar | in the capture group to match either \s or \S

Then a star * after the capture group to match zero to unlimited characters

[Link to example](https://regex101.com/r/rzBfeA/2)

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example in javascript.

```
const texto = `
MESSAGE BEGIN

mary had a little lamb.

little lamb

MESSAGE END
`

const regex = /MESSAGE\sBEGIN[\s\S]*MESSAGE\sEND/gi

console.log(texto.match(regex))

The output is:
[ 'MESSAGE BEGIN\n\nmary had a little lamb.\n\nlittle lamb\n\nMESSAGE END' ]
```

The breaklines were kept.